# Resident alien leaving US and healthcare tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

For tax purpose, I'm considered resident alien for tax year 2017 by substantial presence test. I was on company healthcare plan and COBRA until I left US at the end of September 2017. After that, I did not have any healthcare coverage for the period from October to December.

I am filing my tax with a foreign address and I am not planning to (nor could I) return to US in 2018, if that matters.

Would I be eligible for healthcare coverage exemption if I extend the deadline and wait until I pass the Physical Presence Test?